# How to replace content between two patterns from the file?

Tags: regular-expression, global-command

I've the following format of the file:

```
<common>
fitnes=0
genetic=1
method=0
</common>
<inputs>
foo=bar
bar=foo
</inputs>
<limits>
balance=200.00
</limits>
```

and I would like to delete everything what is between `<inputs>` and `</inputs>` (excluding pattern it-self) and replace it with the content from another file (e.g. `foo.txt`). In other words lines with `foo=bar` and `bar=foo` would be replaced with another content.

Probably it can be similar to how you [delete a multi-line match](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5265/467), like:

```
:g/<inputs/,/inputs>/d
```

but I'm not sure with *what* I should replace the `d` in order to insert the content of another file, but I want to keep the matching pattern.

Similar approach would be to [remove inner content of html tag](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3299/467), like

```
:/<inputs>/norm vitd
```

but then I don't know how would you add into it the content from the file.

Ideally I'm trying to find one liner, since it'll be part of another script.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A substitution can be used to replace a pattern with the result of an expression like this:

```
:keeppatterns %s;<inputs>\zs\_.\{-}\ze</inputs>;\=insert(readfile('test.txt'), '')
```

See `:help sub-replace-expression`

Note that `keeppatterns` prevents the `substitute` command from adding anything to the search history and preserves the "last search pattern register" - see `:help "/`. It's good practice to prevent scripts from unnecessarily modifying Vim's global state with the command modifiers `keepalt`, `keepjumps`, `lockmarks`, `keepmarks`, and `keeppatterns`.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work, at least on a Unix system:

```
:/<inputs>/+1,/<\/inputs>/-1!cat foo.txt
```

It uses the `{range}!{filter}` command to filter the lines from one after `<inputs>` to one before `</inputs>` through the external program `cat foo.txt`. In this case, `cat` ignores its standard input, so the original lines are deleted and replaced by the contents of the file `foo.txt`.

See:

```
:help :range!
:help cmdline-ranges
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach to that from Gary is this:

```
:g/^<inputs>/+,/^<\/inputs>/-d|-r dummy
```

Which first deletes everything in the given pattern, than uses the `:r` command to read the data from file dummy.
Now if you need to extract the filename from the lines between the `<input>/</input>` pattern, it gets a litte bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I feel a macro will be a easier approach.
Especially, if you have various places to do the same.

1. Keep only those 2 files open.
2. Now in the first file start recording by `qa,` (`a` is the record name).
3. Search for the start pattern, press *down*, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, search for the end pattern, press *up*. Now the part which you want to delete is selected. Delete it.
4. Mark the position using `ma` (`a` is the mark name) and save the file.
5. Go to the 2nd file, by `:b2` command and similarly select the part as per your start/end criteria.
6. Come back to this file press `a` to go to that point. Paste there by `p`.
7. Search for end criteria again, and cross the section to not hit it again.
8. Quit recoding by pressing `q`.
9. Repeat the number of times by `40@a`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's fine, but it won't help in this particular case, since I'm looking for non-interactive solution as part of `ex` script where I can specify which file to insert depending on the user input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If this is another attempt to parse XML with non-XML Tools, don't.

The solutions here are valid, but the intention might not be. If the XML is not from a well tamed source, you might get escapes, CDATA, or white spaces in the tag!

So xsltproc from command in vi can deal with that.

Comment: The file is not actually proper XML format, but it's actually not well documented [`ini` file](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/blob/master/conf/ea.ini) having those 3 XML-like tags.